# How can i call a method automatically by the system (webSite) in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a method called `postState()`. This method is supposed to check the state of the post. A post can have 3 states (New, Old, Archived), the method takes a post as its parameters. The method calculates the state based on the days that have passed.

- A 30 day old post is New
- A 30 - 60 day old post is old
- A > 60 day oldpost is Archived

Here's the code:

```
#This method automatically determines the state of the post. Whether it is (New, Old, or          #   Archived)
#The method takes in one parameter which is the post itself
#the method compares the date of which the post was published in and the current date
#It then uses an algorithim to determine the difference in number of days between the current date and the published date
#Based on the amount returned, if the amount is less than 30 days, the state = "NEW", if between 30 and 60, the state = "OLD", if greater than 60, the state = "ARCHIVED"

def postState(self):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    p = Post.objects.get(id = self.id)

    #used if the current year is greater than the year of the published post
    if current_time.year > self.pub_Date.year:
        #this is in case for exmaple the published month of the post is December and the current month is January
        #Although the years are diff yet the diff in days may not be greater than 30
        #Ex: published date: 2012, 12, 28 ----- current date: 2013, 1, 10
        if current_time.month == 1 and self.pub_Date.month ==12 and (current_time.day + (31 - self.pub_Date.day)) > 30:
            p.state = 'Old'
            p.save()
        #this is in case for exmaple the published month of the post is November and the current month is January
        #Although the years are diff yet the diff in days may not be greater than 30 and less than 60
        #Ex: published date: 2012, 11, 1 ----- current date: 2013, 1, 28
        elif current_time.month == 1 and self.pub_Date.month ==11 and (current_time.day + (31 - self.pub_Date.day)) < 60:
            p.state = 'Old'
            p.save()
        else:
            p.state = 'Archived'
            p.save()
    #Used when the current year and Published year of the post are the same
    if current_time.year == self.pub_Date.year:

        day_diff_diff_month = current_time.day + (31 - self.pub_Date.day)
        day_diff_same_month = current_time.day - self.pub_Date.day
        month_diff = current_time.month - self.pub_Date.month
        if month_diff >= 1:
            month_diff = month_diff - 1
            total_diff = (month_diff*31) + day_diff_diff_month
        else:
            total_diff = day_diff_same_month

        if total_diff > 30 and total_diff < 60:
            p.state = 'Old'
            p.save()
        if total_diff > 60:
            p.state = 'Archived'
            p.save()
```

I want this method to run whenever a user opens the post page (post.html)
or whenever he launches the website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think for your problem, the function's source code is not necessary here (In problem description).

Comment: Your comment was correct, So what is the problem? Why you don't call the `postState` function in your view - before rendering template?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code for determining the state of a post seems very complicated. Here's how I'd write it:

   ```
   @property
   def state(self):
       """The state of the post:
       'new' if the post is younger than 30 days;
       'old' if the post is between 30 and 60 days old;
       'archived' if the post is 60 days old or older.

       """
       age = (datetime.datetime.now() - self.pub_Date).days
       if age < 30: return 'new'
       elif age < 60: return 'old'
       else: return 'archived'
   ```
2. If I understand your question correctly, you plan to update the state of a post every time someone looks at it. This is going to cause a lot of database changes. But since a post's state can be computed from the `pub_Date`, why bother? Why not just compute the state whenever you need it, as shown above?

   You can easily issue queries based on computed dates. For example, here's a query that selects only "new" posts:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   Post.objects.filter(pub_Date__gt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30))
   ```

   and here's one that selects only "old" posts:

   ```
   now = datetime.now()
   Post.objects.filter(pub_Date__range = (now - timedelta(days=60),
                                          now - timedelta(days=30))
   ```

   You might also need to figure out how to compute the state in the database engine. The exact details depend on your database, but for example, in MySQL you could use the [`DATEDIFF` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).